# How to calculate a measure based on a decreasing/increasing column's value in DAX

Tags: dax, tabular

I have a Sales table and related dimension tables. MySales table contains columns : Week, StoreID, SalesSeasonID, ProductKey and metrics. My dimensions are related to sales table (Date,SalesSeason,Store,Product tables).

I need to find Sales Quantity (LastYear and LastSeason), as a measure
You can find a sample below:

[image]

My purpose is when user selected `SaleseasonID[4]` then it will return 2 as `SalesQuantity`.

How can I calculate this measure by DAX formula?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
PYSales = 
SUMX ( 
    VALUES ( Table1[YearWeek] ),
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( Table1[SalesQuantity] ),
        ALL ( Table1[SalesSeasonID] ), 
        FILTER ( 
            ALL ( Table1[YearWeek] ),
            Table1[YearWeek] = EARLIER ( Table1[YearWeek] ) - 100
        )
    )
)
```

Worked example PBIX file, using your sample data: https://pwrbi.com/so_55703551/

[image]

Comment: I tried formula but it doesn't give the expected result. Merchyear means: Year period of YearWeek  'Sales Qty_LY:=SUMX(
  VALUES('Date'[MERCHYEAR]);CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[SalesQuantity]);
  ALL('SalesSeasons'[SALESSEASON_ID]);
  FILTER(
   ALL('Date'[MERCHYEAR]);
   'Date'[MERCHYEAR] = EARLIER('Date'[MERCHYEAR])-1)))

Comment: While finding YearWeek:201642 it also has to find SalesSeasonID =2 . I sent a part of data. For Example: Data may contain a row with same productKey, storeID but SalesSeasonID = 3 and YearWeek = 201642

Comment: Your specification is confusing, then - your question asked for user to select SalesSeason value = 4, and return the Sales value from the corresponding week of prior year, which had SalesSeason value = 2. If that's not correct, then perhaps you can [edit] your question, and provide clearer example input / output.